# Why do people are seeming more charistmatic or sympathic, if they are fans of old things?

Tags: social-psychology

I see this very often. Whenever you buy a new car, listen to new music or reading new books you will nerver get the same attention or admiration if you drive an older car, don't listen to trendy music or reading books which are older than myself. And I always wanted to know why? Is it, that you seem more cultural/intellectual if you are a fan of something, which is not that up to date? Is it that it that you seem more "harmless" because you are not interested, that other will admire you, but you do it kind of for yourself and swimming in nostalgia? And I talk about goods or activities which are who are not less qualitative or cost more money.

Comment: In terms of music and literature there is a large cultural acceptance, at least in America, of their quality. You're going against the grain if you think Bach or Shakespeare are bad. You'll find less resistance picking on someone's taste in Miley Cyrus or their love for an F-150.